# Apache rewrite - search two directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am writing an application framework that completely subsides in a sub-directory of the application directory. We use the following htaccess markup to add the path routing we desire:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|assets)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

As you can see, we open the entire assets folder to the public for resources such as css, js, images, etc. Static web files.

What we would like to do is have two asset folders, one in the application directory and another in the framework directory. So, on the physical disk-side, the contents of `/assets/*` and `/framework/assets/*` should both be searched when a user requests a route to the `/assets/*` directory.

In simple terms, we need a rewrite condition compatible with ours to merge the two folders.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to fill in the files/directories, but try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$  -  [L]

RewriteCond /PhysicalDirectoryPath/%{REQUEST_URI}  -f [OR]
RewriteCond /PhysicalDirectoryPath/%{REQUEST_URI}  -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /WebDirectoryPath/$1  [L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*?([^\/]+)$
RewriteCond /PhysicalDirectoryPath/%1  -f [OR]
RewriteCond /PhysicalDirectoryPath/%1  -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /WebDirectoryPath/$1  [L]
```

Comment: I saw this on another answer, it would almost work but I can't figure out how to make it compatible with my original rule :(

Comment: well the [L] flag says that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed. Maybe remove it and test?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
# check if exists in frameowkr/assets
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/assets/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/framework/assets/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /framework/$1 [L]

# check if exists in /assets
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ - [L]
```

Comment: On line 4, is it meant to be a RewriteRule? I have tried it both ways and neither have proved success. More specifically, would it be an issue with having the existing rewrite rule I apply above it? (in the OP)

Comment: Okay, the snippit above works (with the typo fixed) when I comment my existing rules out. How can I make these two conditions compatible?

Comment: @SpencerSharkey sorry, fixed that type. Your routing rule for `/index.php` needs to include `framework` in the condition and needs tobe **after** the asset rules.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule /?assets/([^/]+) /framework/assets/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule /?framework/assets/([^/]+) /assets/$1 [L]
```